# ActiveModel attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

How do I get ActiveRecord attributes method functionality? I have this class:

```
class PurchaseForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name,
                :surname,
                :email

  validates_presence_of :name

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  def initialize(attributes = {}, shop_name)
    if not attributes.nil?
      attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

What I need to do, to have an attributes method to list all names and values from PurchaseForm object?

Comment: In view of the hacky existing answers, the correct answer seems to be "there's no Rails module for that". Personally I'd avoid mimicking the attributes API.

Comment: Maybe the [ActiveModel::Attributes](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemodel/ActiveModel/Attributes) module is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to solve problem with this code:

```
class PurchaseForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :attributes,
                :name,
                :surname,
                :email

  validates_presence_of :name

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Why did you add :attributes to the attr_accessor call ?

Comment: So I can call an attributes method from view...I'm pretty much newbie on Rails so if you have better solution, please share :)

Comment: This solution has drawbacks. If you won't pass all attributes to `.new`, `.attributes` would return incorrect hash with only specified attributes. And second, if you try will to change instance after initialization, say `@purchase_form.name = 'Other name'` and then call `@purchase_form.attributes` the hash would contain old `:name` provided to `.new`.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the refactored variant:

```
class PurchaseForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.attributes
    [:name, :surname, :email]
  end

  attr_accessor *self.attributes

  # your validations

  def to_hash
    self.class.attributes.inject({}) do |hash, key|
      hash.merge({ key => self.send(key) })
    end
  end  
end
```

Now you can easily work with this class:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = PurchaseForm.new({ name: 'Name' })
=> #<PurchaseForm:0x00000002606b50 @name="Name">
irb(main):002:0> a.to_hash
=> {:name=>"Name", :surname=>nil, :email=>nil}
irb(main):003:0> a.email = 'user@example.com'
=> "user@example.com"
irb(main):004:0> a
=> #<PurchaseForm:0x00000002606b50 @name="Name", @email="user@example.com">
irb(main):005:0> a.to_hash
=> {:name=>"Name", :surname=>nil, :email=>"user@example.com"}
```

Even more, if you want to make this behaviour reusable, consider extraction of `.attributes` and `#to_hash` methods into separate module:

```
module AttributesHash
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def attr_accessor(*args)
      @attributes = args
      super(*args)
    end

    def attributes
      @attributes
    end
  end

  included do
    def to_hash
      self.class.attributes.inject({}) do |hash, key|
        hash.merge({ key => self.send(key) })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, just include it to your model and you're done:

```
class PurchaseForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include AttributesHash

  attr_accessor :name, :surname, :email

  # your validations
end
```

Comment: May I suggest using `@attributes ? @attributes += args : @attributes = args` instead of just `@attributes = args` in the concern? This would allow `attr_accessor` to be called multiple times in the class.

Answer (score 15):

`#instance_values` could do the job:

```
class PurchaseForm
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end
end
```

Output sample:

```
purchase.attributes #=> {"name"=>"John", "email"=>"john@example.com"}
```

Comment: Documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-instance_values

Answer (score 6):

Let's try this

`self.as_json`

`=> {:name=>"Name", :surname=>nil, :email=>"user@example.com"}`

Answer (score -3):

would it not be better to use

```
include ActiveModel::Serialization

def attributes
  JSON.parse(self.to_json)
end
```